# Pergunta marcada como não clara, contrariando os comentários

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, comentários, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90801/como-criar-vari%C3%A1vel-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica) à respeito de como criar  variável em JAVA de forma dinâmica.
Os Comentários se iniciaram questionando se não poderia ser um array. Eu espera isso.

Um usuário, nos comentários, viu que de qualquer forma eu tinha que jogar essas variáveis no array, então eu realmente não precisa de variáveis dinâmicas, um array realmente resolveria. Sim, ele me respondeu, eu apliquei e consegui sucesso.

É errado considerar uma resposta como aceita que usa da lógica do código da própria pergunta para responder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quem decide qual a resposta aceite, e que resolveu o teu problema, é quem faz a pergunta.

És livre de aceitar a resposta que quiseres. A comunidade pode votar para mostrar que a resposta é boa, ou má, mas isso é um processo separado. O interessante para quem faz a pergunta é perceber o problema e encontrar uma solução. Se houver uma resposta que faça essas duas coisas excelente. Independentemente de usar lógica do código da pergunta ou mostrar uma lógica nova.

Se achares que a resposta está incompleta pede para completar. É sempre melhor uma explicação a mais do que a menos.

Comment: **_O interessante para quem faz a pergunta é perceber o problema e encontrar uma solução._** Obrigado Sergio, sua sensatez e equilíbrio é sempre bem vinda. Me tranquilizou.